# Defining path in 'to_excel()'

Tags: python, pandas, path, export-to-excel

I am only a beginner and I have a very basic questions for you today:

I am using 'to_excel' to export a pandas data frame as excel file.
The above works but when I now try to specify the the folder (Desktop) in which I would like to have it exported to but that always breaks:

This is what I am using:

```
export_df.to_excel('C:\\stephan\\Desktop\\labels_export.xlsx', index = False)
```

Many many thanks for your help in advance.

Stephan

Comment: `\` is the escape character in python. Try using raw string instead: `r'C:\stephan\Desktop\labels_export.xlsx'`.

Comment: What's the error raised? Saying "it breaks" won't help us identify your problem.

Comment: Try this: `export_df.to_excel('C:/stephan/Desktop/labels_export.xlsx', index = False)`

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang, thanks so much for your input! That helped! I have to write 'User/' instead of 'C;' at the beginning. This code worked: export_df.to_excel(f'/Users/stephan/Desktop/labels_export.xlsx', index = False)

Comment: Thanks @AnupTiwari, I was not aware of this! That really helped.